HostnameConfiguration configured with New Managed Certificate Request is not supported while activating APIM service
I'm trying to set up APIM with Bicep, including a custom-domain.
Bicep:
resource apiManagement 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  ...
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: '...'
    publisherName: '...'
    hostnameConfigurations: [
      {
        type: 'Proxy'
        hostName: 'api.my-domain.com'
        negotiateClientCertificate: false
        defaultSslBinding: true
        certificateSource: 'Managed'
      }
    ]
  }
}

But this gives this error:

HostnameConfiguration configured with New Managed Certificate Request
is not supported while activating APIM service [name].

This only happens on creating the apim instance and custom domain at the same time. If the apim instance is already created, it works fine on the second run.

Have you tried creating an APIM resource first and then updating the custom domain? @Jeppe


HostnameConfiguration configured with New Managed Certificate Request is not supported while activating APIM service [name].

The above configuration is not supported when you are trying to deploy both at once. The workaround for this is, try deploying a APIM service first and then add the changes of hostname configuration.
Alternatively, I would recommend you use'BuiltIn certificate resource if this suits for your requirement rather than a managed certificate as shown below.
hostnameConfigurations: [
      {
        type: 'Proxy'
        hostName: 'api.my-domain.com'
        negotiateClientCertificate: false
        defaultSslBinding: true
        certificateSource: 'BuiltIn'
      }
    ]

Complete bicep code:
param location string = 'westus'
param apimservice string = 'apiservice${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
param sku string = 'Developer'
param skuCountnum int = 2
resource apiManagementService 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: apimservice
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: sku
    capacity: skuCountnum
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: xxxxx
    publisherName: xxxxx
    hostnameConfigurations: [
      {
        type: 'Proxy'
        hostName: 'api.my-domain.com'
        negotiateClientCertificate: false
        defaultSslBinding: true
        certificateSource: 'BuiltIn'
      }
    ]
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:



When I try to deploy using this, I get this error "Invalid parameter: EncodedCertificate or keyVaultId or freeCertificateKeyVaultId should be provided to retrieve the custom SSL certificate for type: Proxy and hostname : api.mydomain.com."

Tried with builtin mode? @Jeppe

yes, as you wrote here.

The same configuration worked for me without any issues. Can you share the code once. @Jeppe
